# Was Jesus hungry or very hungry after 40 days?

Tags: matthew, word-study, luke, translation-philosophy

The temptation of Jesus in the wilderness is summarised thus:

> **Matthew 4:2** (see for example [BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/parallel/matthew/4-2.htm) and also [Luk 4:2](https://biblehub.com/parallel/luke/4-2.htm))
>
> KJV: And when he had fasted forty days and forty nights, he was
>   afterward an *hungred*.
>
> ESV: And after fasting forty days and forty nights, he was *hungry*.
>
> AMP: After He had gone without food for forty days and forty nights,
>   He became *hungry*.
>
> NIV: After fasting forty days and forty nights, he was *hungry*.
>
> NLT: For forty days and forty nights he fasted and became *very
>   hungry*.
>
> MSG: Jesus prepared for the Test by fasting forty days and forty
>   nights. That left him, of course, in a state of *extreme hunger*...
>   (Luk 4:2 here says merely *hungry*)

Based on the more literal translations, the original text probably conveys *hungry*. The more interpreted translations seem to convey *very hungry*.

Translation philosophy differs, but is the use of the extreme form justified here (and maybe elsewhere) in e.g. the NLT? This may affect the way Jesus is portrayed.

Comment: Partly this depends on the widening   meaning of hungry in English. It is now often used to mean no more than about ready for lunch, which is much weaker than what was traditionally meant by hungry. . .

Comment: @davidlol Good point. Seems like popular erosion (or drift in meaning) in language would then necessitate translators to use alternative terms or stronger language.

Comment: Unfortunately, English does not possess an equivalent form for conveying the difference between *was thirsty* and *was thirsting* when it comes to slid food. If it would, then the best translation would be *he was hungering*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Greek in question is [ἐπείνασεν](https://biblehub.com/greek/epeinasen_3983.htm)

which is the 3rd person singular [aorist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aorist_(Ancient_Greek)) form of [πεινάω](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%AC%CF%89) meaning

- intransitively: *I am hungry*
- with a genitive: *I hunger for* or *I crave*

so the natural translation is *he was hungry* or perhaps *he hungered*

Using an extreme form looks like a translator's response to forty days and nights of fasting

Answer (score 0):

The way that the human body responds to not receiving food is:

- initial hunger pains
- after one to three days hunger disappears
- after the body exhausts stored resources it begins to feed off of itself

During this third step hunger comes back with a vengeance. It seems safe to assume that the reason that translators put "very" hungry is that Jesus would have been very hungry!

https://www.quora.com/How-does-starvation-feel-different-from-hunger

Comment: Let's say the "hunger" signal can originate from the brain (emotional, psychological, habits, thought patterns, etc.) and/or the stomach (real hunger when your body actually needs food). I suppose any of these two signals can be strong. So this becomes somewhat subjective. The question then becomes how much freedom a translator should assume in interpreting the text.

Comment: In a way, "Jesus became very hungry" is not more accurate than "Jesus became hungry". It should probably read, "Jesus began starving".